# Using javascript/jQuery to get attribute values from an HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have an HTML string that contains text and images, e.g.

```
<p>...</p>
<img src="..." />
<p>...</p>
```

I need to get the src attribute of the first image. The image may or may not come after a `<p>` and there could be more than one image, or no image at all.

Initially, I tried appending the string to the DOM and filtering. But, if I do this the browser requests all of the external resources. In my situation, this adds a lot of unnecessary overhead.

My initial approach:

```
var holder = $('<div></div>'); 

holder.html(content);

var src = holder.find('img:first').attr('src');
```

How can I get the src of the first image without appending the HTML? Do I need to use a regular expression, or is there a better way?

The solution needs to be javascript/jQuery based – I'm not using any server side languages.

My question is very similar to: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/parsing-html-without-retrieving-external-resources

Thanks

Comment: your question is not clear enough to answer, may be an Example can help. Can u post an example ? what is `content` in your code ?

Comment: `content` refers to the HTML string. The HTML string describes a news article – it could contain text, images or videos. The string comes from a JSON object, e.g. var content = myJSONObj.articleText; where the value could be something like: `Some text...<img src="http://..." border="0" alt="My alt text"><br>More text...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This

```
$("<p><blargh src='whatever.jpg' /></p>").find("blargh:first").attr("src")
```

returns `whatever.jpg` so I think you could try

```
$(content.replace(/<img/gi, "<blargh")).find("blargh:first").attr("src")
```

**Edit**

`/<img/gi` instead of `"<img"`

Comment: Why do you replace img with blargh?

Comment: @DB mentioned that his original approach, loading jQuery objects according to his code, caused the browser to download all the resources. By getting rid of `img` tags I hoped to avoid that problem.

Comment: This approach works, but I had to do `$(content.replace(/<img/gi, "<blargh")).find("blargh:first").attr("src");` It feels a bit dirty...

Comment: wow.. this is the best solution i found till now. Just a thing. In your solution, you have to scan twice the string, and if is a big string this isn't the best solution.. is there another way to find img tag inside a string without loading resource? something like $.parseHTML(myHTML).find('img:first') gives me error..

Comment: Note that img cannot be alone in the string for this to work, so you need to surround it first, e.g., with <p>'s as in the example.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Document Ready: Everything inside this function fires after the page is loaded
        $(document).ready(function () {
                    //Your html string
            var t = "<p><img src='test.jpg'/></p>"
            alert($(t).find('img:first').attr('src'));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just have to take care about having a root element... maybe you must encapsulate your HTML, eg. $('<myRoot>' + htmlStuff + '</myRoot>').find...

Comment: I think this will still have the problem of downloading image files even though you aren't appending the html to the dom. If you create new image elements, browsers download the files right away regardless of whether you append the image elements to the dom.

Comment: Dave Aaron Smith is right – external resources are still downloaded.

Answer (score 5):

I normally use the below:

```
$(content).attr("src")
where 
content = "img src='/somesource/image.jpg'>" //removed < before img for html rendering in this comment
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same issue trying to pull out the src url from an iframe.  Here is a plain JavaScript function that will work for any string:

```
function getSourceUrl(iframe) {
  var startFromSrc = iframe.slice(iframe.search('src'));
  return startFromSrc.slice(5, startFromSrc.search(' ') - 1);
}
```