# How to access the class of an element which is in variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a HTML code in variable I want to access the class of that

```
var test = `
      <h2 class= "text">Hello
      </h2>`
```

This is what I try to access the class of attribute and change the color

```
var query = document.querySelectorAll(".text")
document.getElementById(`${query}`).style.color= red;
```

I want to access the class of `<H2>` tag and in change the color.

Have any way to do that?

Comment: Why first don't render the test then change it color?

Comment: Try adding the `test` HTML string to the DOM first. I'd suggest removing `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` first though, not least because the `body` shouldn't be in the `head`, but also because those elements should already exist in the DOM.

Comment: Accessing the "class" attribute is not how you get to the `style` object anyway. `query[0]` will be a reference to your DOM node, so `query[0].style.color = "red";`

Comment: It's really not clear what the problem is here. Is your HTML really in a string and not a rendered document?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using javascript/jQuery to get attribute values from an HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711710/using-javascript-jquery-to-get-attribute-values-from-an-html-string)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: You appear to have it in your head that you need the class of the `h2` element in order to change the color. The question several people have been trying to get an answer to is, why do you believe this? Do you want to access the CSS rules that make up the class "text" and directly modify them? Or do you want to change the color of just this `h2` element to red? Or do you want to go through every element with the class "text" in the document and change the color to red? Those are three different requests that your brief text could be interpreted to mean. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey  No,It is not

Comment: @Heretic Monkey - There is a html code which is in variable. we can show the "hello" text anyware that is not a problem. But I want to access that html code and change the color and display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the string before you add it to the html page.

```
var test = `
      <h2 class= "text">Hello
      </h2>`

test = $(test).css("color", "red")
```

**Demo**

```js
var test = `
      <h2 class= "text">Hello
      </h2>`

test = $(test).css("color", "red")

$("body").append(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`query` is an array, and to get the 1st (only) one, just do `query[0].style.color = red;`
The reason it's an array is because `document.querySelectorAll()` returns an array of elements.
**But element MUST be in the DOM**

Comment: Thanks, But this is not the exactly expected answer. DOM is in variable I want to access the class of DOM which is in variable

Answer (score -2):

Updating my answer now I realise your HTML is in a string. Not sure why you're doing it this way but I digress.

You just include inline styling within your string.

```
var test = `<html> 

  <head>
    <body>
      <h2 style="color: red;" class="text">Hello
      </h2>
    </body>
  </head>

</html>`
```

Comment: Why must they include styling in the string to get the value of the class attribute?

Comment: Prior to changing the answer, I offered the OP the jQuery selector code to change colour but that wasn't required. Not much information on the context of the question so assuming OP simply wants the end result to have red styling, then the above works fine.

Comment: In my question I used a variable and include the html tags there now that variable has html code right?. Now I want to access the class of that "<h2 class = 'text'" , Then set the color to that class "classname[0].style.color = red". something like that. In above answer we can directly use inline css it's OK. But my question doesn't have same as code that you put here, **There is a code it is in variable I want to access the class of that code** That's it