# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse(<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, error-handling

I'm working on an ajax call to an API. and upon calling this call, I keep running into this error. Please help. Ive been trying at this for hours and not sure what the issue is. Ive taken out the

`JSON.parse` and added them back to see if that will help but still no progress.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         //url: 'http://aeM/api/getDataId',
        url: '/bin/soupservice.getDataAccordToId.html',
        //async: false,
        data: IDschema,
        //contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            // Show image container
            $("#wait").css("display", "block");
        },
        
    success:function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(jqXHR.status);
   
        if (JSON.parse(data)) {
            let fileDeviceData = [];
            let uploadDate = [];
            fileDeviceData = data;
            let deviceNameFromFileData = [];
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, element) {
                dataInFile.push(element.file);
                deviceNameFromFileData.push(element.deviceName);
                //push an object while interacting with API. used to get similar index locations for later use
                duplicateIdCheckedList.push({
                    "deviceName":element.deviceName,
                    "lastUploadDate":element.lastUploadDate.split(" ")[0] ,
                    "fileName": element.deviceName+ " "+element.lastUploadDate.split(" ")[0],
                    "id":element.id
                    
    
                });
                let utcTime = element.lastUploadDate;
                let utcText = moment(utcTime).format("L LT");
                let anotherway = moment.utc(utcTime).local().format("L LT");
                let firstConvertedString = anotherway.split("/").join("-").replace(",", "");
                uploadDate.push(firstConvertedString.split(":").join("-").replace(",", ""));
            })
            //call on the findDuplicateIndex function to organize all the files that will be consolidated together
            duplicates=findDuplicateIndex(duplicateIdCheckedList);
            valuesforBrowserTime = uploadDate
            exportAsTxt(deviceNameFromFileData, valuesforBrowserTime);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are requesting a `.html` file and passing data to `JSON.parse` that expect a [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp) format.

You may need to parse using a different method.

Comment: any idea what method to use??

Comment: If you are in the browser you could use `innerHTML` of some element. Then you can walk the DOM. In NodeJS you could use something like [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Comment: @ user12750353  im using Jquery. any clue on how to do it in that framework?

Comment: [jQuery.parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) ?

Comment: do you see the $.each function I have?? How would using nodes work for getting attributes from each element??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711710/using-javascript-jquery-to-get-attribute-values-from-an-html-string. First google result.

Comment: hey I justfigured out the issue. JSON.parse works only for ajax responses less than a certain size. anything bigger than that size I get that error