# How to get the class name dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am dynamically manipulating DOM.

I have the HTML elements

```
var customFileData = '<input type="file" class="file-upload-button" value="submit"'+
  <div class="dynamic-progress-bar-234342123"></div>'+
  <div class="success-message"></div>'
```

Now - I want to get the className of the firstDiv. How do I get it?

Either jQuery or JavaScript both works. But I can't do ---

```
$(div[class*='dynamic-progress-bar']).attr('class')
```

Because, it's not yet manipulated to DOM.

When I do --

```
$(customFileData).attr('class');
```

Getting Result --- file-upload-button

Any idea, how to get the first div className?

Comment: Similar to provided answer:  `var j = $("<div>").html(customFileData)` then do whatever you want, eg `j.find("div").first()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using javascript/jQuery to get attribute values from an HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711710/using-javascript-jquery-to-get-attribute-values-from-an-html-string)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the HTML will be valid (currently there's a missing `>` for input which I've added in the code below)

The following works

```js
var customFileData = '<input type="file" class="file-upload-button" value="submit">'+
                     '<div class="dynamic-progress-bar-234342123"></div>'+
                     '<div class="success-message"></div>';

var x = $('input+div', `<root>${customFileData}</root>`).attr('class');

console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Though, my jQuery is very weak, as it should be, so there's probably a better way than that!!

vanilla javascript version - DOMParser

```js
var customFileData = '<input type="file" class="file-upload-button" value="submit">'+
                     '<div class="dynamic-progress-bar-234342123"></div>'+
                     '<div class="success-message"></div>';

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(customFileData, 'text/html');
var x = doc.querySelector('div');

console.log(x.className);
```

vanilla javascript `document.createElement`

```js
var customFileData = '<input type="file" class="file-upload-button" value="submit">'+
                     '<div class="dynamic-progress-bar-234342123"></div>'+
                     '<div class="success-message"></div>';

var doc = document.createElement('root');
doc.innerHTML = customFileData;
var x = doc.querySelector('div');

console.log(x.className);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to create a new DOM element of some sort and add the above HTML string using `insertAdjacentHTML` you can then use `querySelector` with whatever expression you need to find whichever element you need. Specifically here:

```js
var customFileData = '<input type="file" class="file-upload-button" value="submit" />' + 
'<div class="dynamic-progress-bar-234342123"></div>' + 
'<div class="success-message"></div>';


let div=document.createElement('div');
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',customFileData);
let res=div.querySelector('div');

console.info(res.className)

div=null;
```