# Get attribute from HTML string (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I'm trying to extract an image attribute from a HTML that's pulled in as a String.

Attempting to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/40311944/2981404 returns:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')`

My code is as follows:

```
const html[0] = '<img src="/img/image-example.png" class="image" title="What Im looking for..." alt="This is an example image">'
const startFromTitle = html[0].slice(
  html[0].search('title')
)
const title = startFromTitle.slice(5, startFromTitle.search(' ') - 1)
console.log(title) // expected "What Im looking for..."
```

I'd love to use jQuery, but on this project, I can't.

Comment: Declare `html` as an array first, before assigning `html[0]` a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a temporary `div` element in DOM **:**

```js
const htmlStr = '<img src="/img/image-example.png" class="image" title="What Im looking for..." alt="This is an example image">';

var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
tmpDiv.innerHTML = htmlStr;

console.log(tmpDiv.querySelector('.image').getAttribute('title'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You must declare `html` as `const` first and then assign the html string to html[0].

And then you can remove `title="` from the string (`withoutTitle`) and then search for `'"'` to find the end of the attribute.

```js
const html = [];

html[0] = '<img src="/img/image-example.png" class="image" title="What Im looking for..." alt="This is an example image">';

const startFromTitle = html[0].slice(
  html[0].search('title')
);

const withoutTitle = startFromTitle.slice(
  7
);

const title = withoutTitle.slice(0, withoutTitle.search('"'));

console.log(title);
```

Comment: Thanks, I should've included that line in my initial code. It does exist.